# Rails selector gives undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the line of code:

```
f.select(:birth_day, options_for_select((1..31)), {:include_blank => false }, {:id =>     'select1'})
```

Yet when I run the relevant part of my site it gives

undefined method `birth_day' for #

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? birth_day is clearly not a method but the name of the parameter that the select tag submits.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model that this form is associated with doesn't have method (neither field) called `birth_day`.

You probably want to add `birth_day` field to your model - or add `attr_accessor :birth_day` to this model (note that this field wouldn't be saved in the database - but you can do something with it in callback).

Comment: Thanks a ton I never would have figured that out if it weren't for you

Answer (score 1):

`select_tag` and `f.select` are completely different methods and they're not equivalent. Having `select_tag` you can declare whatever you want, e.g:

```
form_tag '/some_path' do 
  select_tag :birth_day, options_for_select((1..31))
end
```

Remember that `select_tag :birth_day` means that it is not associated with any object (so that `birth_day` may be accessible within controller as `params[:birth_day]`), but again, it is not associated with any object.

Having `f.select` on the other hand, enforces you to use `form_for`, e.g:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.select :birth_day, options_for_select((1..31))
end
```

Such definition of form enforces that `@user` has to have `birth_day` field, either declared as `attr_accessor :birth_day`, or given in database.